# Can I send my resume to several recruiters from the same company? (not agency)

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I'm looking for a new job in a technical area (Software Dev) and I'm building a list of in-house recruiters of several companies I'd like to work for.

Is it a good idea to email my resume to several of them at the same time? Some recruiters post which teams they are hiring for, many do not.

I don't want to lose an opportunity because I stepped on some tacit rule regarding recruitment.

I'm not working with any agency. I'm doing this 100% on my own.

Comment: Are you saying you applied to several open positions at the same company but those positions are each assigned to their own recruiter?

Answer (score 2):

Recruiter performance is often measured by the number of contacts and hires -- by submitting to multiple people within the organization you may create confusion for them internally.

I would submit to one initially -- if you do not receive a timely response, then send to another. Good recruiters will follow up with you as soon as they can, since it's kind of what they do.

Answer (score 0):

It can't hurt.  It's likely that the resume will end up as a single copy in their database.  (Yes, they go into a database).  But at least all those recruiters will have you in mind for current gigs, without having to LOOK for you.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple recruiters in a company they may be responsile for hiring for different positions.

First, you can find a connection or a friend in that company and ask them who should you contact for each position. You can easily find this out by calling the administrator of that company asking for this as well.

If you cannot find any information on who is responsible for which department, then as @mcknz mentioned, first submit to recruiter A and mention that you are interested in position X, Y and Z. Maybe you can create a separate resume for each position.

The recruiter may come back to you and may say they can help you with position X, but with Y and Z you have to contact other people (which seems unlikely because they usually forward your application internally).

Then if you did not hear from recruiter A after a couple of days to a week or so, contact recruiter B of that company and mention that you already have contacted A already and have not heard from him.